# Is it possible to get historical data, more than 1 month, from Cloud-SQL instance metrics, e.g. memory, CPU, IO to perform trend analysis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When I am in the main page for a cloud SQL instance in the web console, I have access to a chart that shows me CPU, Mem, IO for up 30 days, can I have more than 30 days to graph trends?

I searched in Stackdriver without success.
I have searched in "Google Cloud SQL" group discussion without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your data from Stackdriver. Common destinations are BigQuery, Pub/Sub, and Cloud Storage.

The Stackdriver retention period varies based upon the type of log data, from 30 to 400 days. [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods)

This article will help you understand how to export Stackdriver logs. [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/design-patterns-for-exporting-stackdriver-logging)

This is a good article written by Marek Bartik. [link](https://medium.com/@marekbartik/gcp-stackdriver-logging-export-to-bucket-and-extract-textpayload-from-json-with-cloud-functions-4696798df803)

You cannot recover data after the retention period. You need to export before data expires (discarded).

Part of your question is to graph trends for longer than 30 days for Cloud SQL. You will need to export the data to another analysis tool for display.

There are third-party products that will do everything for you. Google search for products that might fit your requirements. This article explains how to connect Stackdriver with a third party. [link](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/How-to-connect-Stackdriver-to-external-monitoring.html)